# Need to redirect a domain to another domain without affecting email

Tags: dns, subdomain, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

we have 2 domains setup example.co.in and another example.com. Email MX records are pointed to example.co.in domain. As of now example.co.in has our app. I want to redirect application URL  example.co.in to example.com. Only Domain need to be redirected and all sub domains should be same. Planned to do 301 redirect on domain level. I am not sure how MX records will be affected on this.

Can someone guide on this whats the best way to do this ?

Comment: email has NOTHING to do with http. You can redirect http any way you want. email won't be affected, unless you modify the MX records in DNS.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Let me go ahead then.

Answer (score 2):

301 redirect are page base. It won't affect mail delivery.

https://moz.com/blog/url-rewrites-and-301-redirects-how-does-it-all-work

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)